# Add/Remove Twitter Bootstrap Alerts in AngularJS with fadeIn/fadeOut effect

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

All is in my title, I implemented Twitter Bootstrap alerts in my angularJS app (using [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)) :

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

But I don't know how I could apply a fadeIn/fadeOut animation on show/hide events.
I imported [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) so that I already have animation classes available.

Thank you for your help

Comment: maybe add a style on alert, with fade in , and when you click on close, use fadeout, when user click on button.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I didn't manage to add the fadeOut class on click...

Comment: [here is example](http://jsfiddle.net/geonunez/pWG2S/) just add your style when clicking on close

Comment: No this is not working when I have this in my view : `<alert class="animated fadeIn" ng-class="class" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>`and then in the corresponding controller : `$scope.class = "fadeOut";` got the error : `Syntax Error: Token '"alert-"' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [class "alert-" + (type || "warning")] starting at ["alert-" + (type || "warning")].`

Comment: Are your alerts working properly without fades? Because i got a similar error because of version mismatch/breaking change.
See the [release log](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) and [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2175) on github.